# Compare multiple numbers in an array

Tags: c#, arrays

I have this problem and I'm stuck. I'm a beginner in software development.

You get a list of N students and a list of grades for each student. Every student gets coins. A student which has bigger grade than his neighbors from list earns more coins than them. Find the coins which every student must receive. I have to give students coins which has bigger grade.

Data input

```
3
Ionel
Mihai
Elena
9
10
8
```

Data output

```
Ionel 1
Mihai 3
Elena 1.
```

Here is my code.

```
          static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            string[] studentsList = FillArray(number);
            int[] studentsGrades = ConvertList(FillArray(number));
            PrintResult(studentsList, GetCoins(studentsGrades));

        }

        static string[] FillArray(int number)  // filling array with names of students
        {
            string[] result = new string[number];
            for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
            {
                result[i] = Console.ReadLine();
            }
            return result;
        }

        static int[] ConvertList(string[] array)
        {
            int[] result = new int[array.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
            {
                result[i] = Convert.ToInt32(array[i]);
            }

            return result;
        }
        static int[] GetGrades(int number) // give grades of each student
        {
            int[] result = new int[number];
            for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
            {
                result[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            return result;
        }
        static int[] GetCoins(int[] input) // this is the method where I'm stuck.
{
        int[] coins = new int[input.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < coins.Length; i++)
        {
            coins[i] = 1;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i > 0 && (input[i] > input[i - 1]))
            {
                if (coins[i] <= coins[i - 1])
                {
                    coins[i] = coins[i - 1] + 1;
                }
            }
            if (i < input.Length - 1 && input[i] > input[i + 1])
            {
                if (coins[i] == coins[i + 1])
                {
                    coins[i]++;
                }
                if (i > 0 && input[i] > input[i-1])
                {
                    coins[i - 1]++;
                }
            }
        }
        return coins;
    }



        static void PrintResult(string[] array, int[] array2)  // print the final result
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
            {
                array[i] += " " + array2[i];
            }

            foreach (string student in array)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(student);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The program displays

```
    Ionel 1
    Mihai 2
    Elena 1.
  // this is wrong.
```

The correct answer is

```
    Ionel 1
    Mihai 3
    Elena 1
   // the correct answer
```

I'm not sure, but the problem is at the ***GetCoins*** method. Please help.
Thanks!

Comment: It seems, you have **Leet Code problem #135** (just change *students* to *children* and *coins* to *candies*) https://leetcode.com/problems/candy/

Comment: I don't understand how you get from input to output

Comment: @Charlieface what do you mean?

Comment: What steps take you from "Data input" to "Data output"?

Comment: the FillArray method, ConvertList method, GetGrades method, GetCoins method.

Comment: @Charlieface is not the best answer?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko not really, is not working on my case